# 98-100% memory use, no process uses more than 25MB

Tags: windows-8, memory, process-explorer

I am having intermittent issues with my gaming computer. Sometimes, while playing Battlefield 3 (only 2 times the problem has occured), my memory usage goes to 100% of my 16GB machine. I close down BF3 (which is unplayable at this point), open up task manager, and no process uses more than 25MB of memory. Process Explorer shows much the same thing.

The problem disappears aftera reboot.

Any ideas what can be going on here?

[image: Task manager]
[image: Process explorer]
[image: Poolmon x86]
[image: Poolmon x64]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may have a bad driver which leaks pool memory. Start the TasmkMgr and look at the non paged pool usage value. If this is several GB, you need to do the following:

Install the [Windows Driver Kit](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/), run [poolmon.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ntdebugging/troubleshooting-pool-leaks-part-2-poolmon) and look which pooltag causes the high memory usage. If you found the tag, open the cmd prompt and run

```
findstr /s <Pooltag> *.sys
```

and look which driver is shown. If it happens while playing games, update the GPU driver. The ATI 12.10 driver is known to cause it. Install the [13.1 WHQL driver](https://www.amd.com/en/support) to fix it.

Comment: I do have the 12.10 ATI driver installed. Upgrading now, hope the problem disappears.

Comment: 12.11 beta drivers crash whenever BF3 is started, unfortunately, so rolling back.

Comment: run poolmon and look if the AMD driver is really the cause.

Comment: poolmon output added. Seems like `MINI` is the culprit. Potential matches: `arc.sys`, `atikmdag.sys`, `crashdmp.sys`, `diskdump.sys`. I am assuming `atikmdag.sys` is the issue, so I am trying another upgrade of the ATI driver.

Comment: ok, this can be the AMD driver. AMD releaed the 13.1 WHQL driver. Try this one.

Comment: @VegardLarsen have you fixed the issue? Did updating the AMD driver fixed it?

Comment: Yes, the problem went away after newer drivers appeared.

Comment: ok, this is what I expected.

Comment: This problem is back again with 13.11 beta 8

Comment: @Pork'n'Bunny is it again the MINI tag?

Comment: In my case poolmon showed trouble with the Wfpn tag. This is a common issue with the Killer e2200 NIC. The workaround was to disable the NDU service with `sc config NDU start=disable` at an elevated command prompt (see: http://damjank.blogspot.com/2012/11/windows-8-rtm-memory-leak-ndusys_15.html)